# Which RBL's does sophos use?

Tags: spam, rbl, sophos

Anyone know where I can find the a list of which RBL's Sophos use's? I have checked their website with no luck, and currently awaiting a response from their technical support.

Thank You in advance

Kevin

Comment: Why not look on [Sophos website](http://www.sophos.com)?

Comment: They do not appear on the sophos website, and I am waiting to hear from there technical support but thought I would ask here While I waited!

Comment: Worth putting that information in your question here to avoid getting your question voted down.  People don't take to kindly to questions that don't show someone has done a basic search for an answer already :-)  Update your question, and I'll remove the down vote (I can't otherwise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Sophos maintain their own DNSBL which is part of their [anti-spam offering](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/email/puremessage-for-unix.aspx).